# On iOS 11, Sticker Pack extension crashes on first launch

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

The first time I run my Sticker Pack extension on a simulator, I get the following crash:

`2017-10-25 14:56:10.513268-0700 MobileSMS[94610:5136614] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘NSInvalidArgumentException’, reason: ‘attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x60c00023b820> {length = 2, path = 0 - 9223372036854775807}’`

I didn't see an answer for this on StackOverflow, so I'm posting this question and will answer it below. Let me know if this is incorrect!

Answer (score 8):

The simulator is actually trying to scroll to the sticker pack app icon and press it. For some reason, the simulator doesn't automatically enable your sticker pack, so there isn't an icon to press.

**To enable your sticker pack:**

1. On simulator, open message thread.
   [image]
2. Tap the ellipsis (three dot) button at bottom.
   [image]
3. Tap edit at top-right, then enable your app.
   [image]

Re-run your app and it will work! I wrote a [blog post](http://huntermonk.com/2017/10/28/sticker-pack-first-run.html) about this fix. The post is essentially the same content I've posted here.

Comment: I am running on my device. Its crashing